# Publishing Azure APIM Portal Does Not Work

Tags: azure-api-management

I am trying to publish the Azure APIM developer portal - it is enabled for user/pass - authentication.  We haven't customized it and are just trying to get it to work.

When I click publish and go to view the portal in a different browser I get the following message

**"This is a home page of the Developer portal - an automatically generated, fully customizable website for publishing your API documentation where consumers can discover APIs, learn how to use them, request access, and try them out.
The content hasn't been published yet. You can do so in "Developer portal" section of your API Management Service in the Azure portal. Learn more."**

When I go back to the Portal publish page, it resets to show "Publish" as if nothing has happened?

Are there any logs or anything I can test to get this to work?

BTW - the Legacy portal works 100%.

Thank you.

Comment: APIM Portal needs to be republished after making changes like custom domain assigning, identity provider updating, changing product/sign-in terms, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is what we have done, multiple times, but still we get the above error message with no reason why?

Comment: Can you show the screenshot and steps how you created, published APIs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Created the APIM instance and added the HTTP Trigger API from Function App and published the developer portal by enabling the CORS option also.
[image]

Next, I have created the user and given all APIs Level access in the APIM Instance and opened both deprecated and legacy portal in different browser, logged in with the non-administrative user:
[image]

You can see logs of all activities in the Activity log of APIM Instance:
[image]

To see the Function App API imported in the APIM Instance, you have to add that API to the products subscribed by that user:
[image]

Published the developer portal again with new changes:
[image]
Activity Logs:
[image]

Result:
[image]

You can check each log activity from the Activity log to see complete details whether the operation publish or other is succeeded and how much time it took to complete.